# React JS resuse components

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

I am doing an my first react JS app and I want to shorten my code but I don't know how can I do it.

```
import "./App.css";
import ExpenseItem from "./components/NoteItem";
import AppHeader from "./components/AppHeader";

function App() {
  var notes = [
    {
      title: "To do",
      date: new Date(2022, 11, 12),
      body: "Alagaan mo sarili mo mark",
    },

    {
      title: "To do1",
      date: new Date(2022, 11, 12),
      body: "Alagaan mo sarili mo mark1",
    },

    {
      title: "To do2",
      date: new Date(2022, 11, 12),
      body: "Alagaan mo sarili mo mark2",
    },

    {
      title: "To do3",
      date: new Date(2022, 11, 12),
      body: "Alagaan mo sarili mo mark3",
    },
  ];


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppHeader></AppHeader>
 
      <ExpenseItem
        title={notes[0].title}
        date={notes[0].date}
        body={notes[0].body}
      ></ExpenseItem>
      <ExpenseItem
        title={notes[1].title}
        date={notes[1].date}
        body={notes[1].body}
      ></ExpenseItem>
      <ExpenseItem
        title={notes[2].title}
        date={notes[2].date}
        body={notes[2].body}
      ></ExpenseItem>
      <ExpenseItem
        title={notes[3].title}
        date={notes[3].date}
        body={notes[3].body}
      ></ExpenseItem>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How can I use looping so that the  will be only typed once. Thank you for the help. Is it possible to shorten this code?

Please help me, i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to shorten your code as below:

```
import "./App.css";
import ExpenseItem from "./components/NoteItem";
import AppHeader from "./components/AppHeader";

function App() {
  var notes = [
    {
      title: "To do",
      date: new Date(2022, 11, 12),
      body: "Alagaan mo sarili mo mark"
    },
    {
      title: "To do1",
      date: new Date(2022, 11, 12),
      body: "Alagaan mo sarili mo mark1"
    },
    {
      title: "To do2",
      date: new Date(2022, 11, 12),
      body: "Alagaan mo sarili mo mark2"
    },
    {
      title: "To do3",
      date: new Date(2022, 11, 12),
      body: "Alagaan mo sarili mo mark3"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppHeader></AppHeader>
      {notes.map(({ title, date, body }) => (
        <ExpenseItem title={title} date={date} body={body} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: don't forget to add a `key` to elements produced by map ;)
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys